# How to remove used flowFiles from flowFile queues?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I  want   to  get   only  one first  flowFile  from  success queue and  use  its  data for   later  process, and  then  remove  it  from  the process session.  When I  get  this  file  and extract  its  data  to   another  flowfile,  the used flowfile on which  I  have made  `session.remove()`  operation physically  is  in   success  queue. How  should I  prevent this? Here  is my  code  and  photo   of workflow:

**WORKFLOWF  IMAGE**

[image: WORKFLOWF IMAGE]

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import groovy.lang.*

def flowfileList = session.get(1)
if(flowfileList.size() >1) {
  session.remove(flowfileList)
  return
}
def name=""
def count=" "
def  filename=" "
def value= 0.0;
def numb=0;
def tryOnce=0;
for(FlowFile f in flowfileList){

 name=f.getAttribute("realName")
 count=f.getAttribute("count")
  filename=f.getAttribute("filename")
 value= count as Double;
 numb=Math.round(value)

}
session.remove(flowfileList);


while(tryOnce<1){
def  flowFile=session.create();
 flowFile=session.putAttribute(flowFile,"filename",filename)
 flowFile=session.putAttribute(flowFile,"name",name)
 flowFile=session.putAttribute(flowFile,"count",numb.toString())
 flowFile=session.putAttribute(flowFile,"check","this")
tryOnce=tryOnce+1
session.transfer(flowFile,REL_SUCCESS)
}
```